# DotNet Nuget Linux: Unable to load the service index

Tags: .net-core, proxy, nuget

Whenever I try to run 'dotnet run' (on RHEL 7) I get this error:
(I `xxx`'ed some parts I can't show)

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.407/NuGet.targets(128,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [xxx.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.407/NuGet.targets(128,5): error :   Connection refused [xxx.csproj]

The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.
```

I am behind a proxy and already set it in the nuget config. I also have 2 package sources which both need to access the proxy.
This is the config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <config>
        <add key="http_proxy" value="http://xxx:xxx" />
    </config>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="xxx" value="https://xxx/v3/index.json"/>
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

I can also verify that the config is applied (at least somehow) by checking the registered package sources:

```
> dotnet nuget list source
Registered Sources:
  1.  nuget.org [Enabled]
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
  2.  xxx [Enabled]
      https://xxx/v3/index.json
```

It shouldn't be a proxy issue, because curl works:

```
> curl -x http://xxx:xxx -I https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...

> curl -x http://xxx:xxx -I https://xxx/v3/index.json
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was that the proxy from the nuget config was completely ignored (I don't know why). A local config (inside the project folder) didn't help too.

This is what fixed my issue:

I added the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables and cleaned any remaining cache files. I also added `DOTNET_SYSTEM_NET_HTTP_USESOCKETSHTTPHANDLER=0` to the environment, but I'm not 100% sure if this was necessary.